# Adding classes to my Nav bar

Tags: jquery, html

Looking for a bit of help with some jQuery, I am looking to add a class to the first UL under the Nav tag and I am looking to add a different class to every li that is a parent to a UL.

The code for the Nav bar is below, Also is my current jQuery code which doesn't seem to want to work.

I have to add them to jQuery due to the platform I am developing for.

Thanks in advance for all the help
George

```
<nav class="uk-navbar" id="navBarNav">
<ul ADD CLASS HERE>
    <li class="uk-active"><a href="index.html" rel="self" id="current">Home</a></li>
    <li ADD CLASS HERE><a href="page1/index.html" rel="self">page2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page1/page4/index.html" rel="self">sub1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page1/page5/index.html" rel="self">sub2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page2/index.html" rel="self">page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3/index.html" rel="self">page4</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$('#navBarNav ul').addClass('uk-navbar-nav');
$('#navBarNav ul li').has(ul).addClass('uk-pearent');
```

Comment: Is your code inside document.ready(...) - is the dom ready to be queried?

Comment: Does typing `$('#navBarNav ul')` into a JavaScript console return the element you're trying to make changes to? It's possible the the selector somehow isn't finding the element at all. The DOM not being ready could be one cause of that.

Comment: Well idiot of the night award goes to me, forgot to link the JS File to the HTML Doc.....

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   $('#navBarNav ul').addClass('uk-navbar-nav');
   $('#navBarNav ul li ul').removeClass('uk-navbar-nav').addClass('uk-pearent');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyaq5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#navBarNav').children('ul').first().addClass('uk-navbar-nav');
```

and

```
$('#navBarNav').find('ul').closest('li').addClass('uk-pearent');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line

```
$('#navBarNav ul').addClass('uk-navbar-nav');
```

Is that it adds the class to both of the uls. Try

```
$('#navBarNav ul:first').addClass('uk-navbar-nav');
```

Answer (score 0):

one trick i normally do is to create a class name that is unique enough for each of the li under the ul, then use JQuery to grab the class and by using a for-loop to add additional class to those li.  here is some pseduo code.

```
<ul>
  <li class="unique_class"> Your content</li>
  <li class="unique_class">Your content </li>
</ul>
```

in the script section

```
var contents = $(".unique_class")
for (i=0; i<contents.length; i++)
{
    contents[i].addClass('the class you want to add')
}
```